# Neo4J and Spring returning empty relationships

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data

For a school project we're trying to set up a family tree in Neo4j with Spring Boot and Spring data. As of now, we are able to return a list of all the connected nodes. However, we are left with an empty set of relations. Spring gives us an array of objects that should represent the nodes, but they are all empty.

```
[{
"id": 88,
"uuid": "790f0720-59f6-49ee-b444-7bea92c158b6",
"name": "Bert",
"sex": "M",
"birthYear": 1478513136564,
"deathYear": 1478513136564,
"city": "Groningen",
"causeOfDeath": "",
"ownerId": "d82917ee-a4b2-405e-ac0b-ee06188d7fb2",
"note": "test",
"married": [
  {}
],
"children": [
  {},
  {},
  {}
]}
```

We're stuck with the relations that aren't being displayed. How are we able to fetch those relations?

We are using

```
public interface GenogramDao extends GraphRepository<Person> {
}
```

And

```
@RequestMapping("/findall")
public Iterable<Person> allAsList() {
    return dao.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating getters and setters for the Marrige object?

Comment: Getters are enough in this case